# Get access to model without related_name

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have model Calendar:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Here is model with related_name:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, related_name='base')
    code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=2, default='DE')
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is no problem because I can get access to calendar via:

```
base_ids = self.calendar.base.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

But I have another model without related_name:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I tried with:

```
post_id = self.calendar_set.themes.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

but it's no working.

Comment: is there any reason why you're not adding a related_name?

Comment: It's not clear what model `self` is in the two examples above. What is `themes`?

Comment: self.calendar = Calendar @Alasdair

Comment: OK, but the second example doesn't even use `self.calendar`. What is `self` in the second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **never** any requirement to add a related_name in order to get access to a model. (The only time you ever *need* to add one is when there is a conflict.) The default here would be `post_set`, which works fine.

Comment: Thanks @daniel-roseman